# Trying to get a RTL2832U DVB-T and a TBS 5922SE DVBS2 DVB-S2 to "cohabit"

Tags: drivers, realtek, dvb-t, v4l

Trying to get two DVB devices working at the same time and struggling. One's a TBS 5922SE, which is a dvb-s device and is now working and the other is a RealTek RTL2832U, a dvb-t, both USB.

The RealTek RTL2832U has been supported by Ubuntu since 12.04 I believe, (I'm on 14.04), with included drivers from Ubuntu and was working fine, but the TBS means having to compile and then remove *all* the files from `/lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/media` before installing with `sudo make install`.

That, presumably, is why the RTL device has stopped working. :( It says:

```
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device' in /var/log/syslog
```

I've tried recompiling the old drivers for the RTL from  https://github.com/ambrosa/DVB-Realtek-RTL2832U-2.2.2-10tuner-mod_kernel-3.0.0.git, but they don't compile.

They give an error:

```
*** No rule to make target `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl''
```

I assume it might simply be a matter of copying back some of the files from `/lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/`, but how would I go about finding out which ones? :(

This is getting a bit beyond me, tbh so any help ideas or guidance greatly appreciated :)

Further information:

I've been examining this issue further and have found a post on another site which I believe is from the person who writes the drivers for the TBS devices... as I write, it's located here...

http://www.tbsdtv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=8816#p30474

But it simply says...

'Backport current rtl28xx driver from official V4L to TBS V4L.'

But with no further help or guidance I'm still stuck :(

Comment: Trying to fetch some better experts then me...

Comment: OK! In the absence of any responses, this is what I'm planning to do.